# Union # results together

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show 80k results for movies and 80k results for tv, so 160k results together. Here is the query I currently have:

```
select country_of_tld, content_type_id, provider_id, name
from main_iteminstance where content_type_id='movie'
limit 80000
  union
select country_of_tld, content_type_id, provider_id, name
from main_iteminstance where content_type_id='tv season'
limit 80000
```

However, this only gives me 80k results instead of 160k. How would I get 160k results, 80k moves and 80k tv seasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding parentheses

```
(select country_of_tld, content_type_id, provider_id, name
from main_iteminstance where content_type_id='movie'
limit 80000)
union all
(select country_of_tld, content_type_id, provider_id, name
from main_iteminstance where content_type_id='tv season'
limit 80000)
```